# issue implementing an AsyncTask thread

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I have the following issue...I'm implementing a `QR code` game in my android application...that is done by launching this `intent`:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(
                           "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                   intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
                   intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                   startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

In other words I start the `Barcode Scanner` application.

Want I want to do is launch this application and even if the user starts scanning a barcode or not the application will close automatically after two minutes.

Of course if the user doesn't close it mean time.

I tried implementing an `AsyncTask` thread like this:

**in onCreate()**

```
initTask=new InitTask();
initTask.execute();
```

**outside of onCreate()**

```
private class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

           protected Void doInBackground(Void...unused){

           new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                 try {
                   Thread.sleep(20000);
                 } 
                 catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 Intent intent = new Intent(
                           "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                   intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
                   intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                   startActivityForResult(intent, 0); 
                }
               }.run();
                this.cancel(true);


           return null;

       }

   }
```

**outside of onCreate()**

```
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
     //..........
    }
```

The problem is that the app gets opened but it doesn't close automatically after 2 minutes.
Does someone know how could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

```
private class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
   Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
   intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
   intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
   startActivityForResult(intent, 1515);
}
protected Void doInBackground(Void...unused){

try
{
       Thread.sleep(20000);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
return null;

}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
{

   finishActivity(1515);

}


}
```

**Activity Result**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == 1515) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                    String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                    System.out.println("it is ok");
                    // Handle successful scan
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // Handle cancel
                    System.out.println("it is cancel");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: you misunderstood me!I want the app to run and after 2 minutes to be closed.This piece of code.Put the thread for sleep...then launches the intent and never close it!

Comment: when you want close app and when you want start intent?

Comment: The intent(and the app) is started by pressing that button and I want the app(meaning the Barcode Scanner) to be stopped after 2 minutes automatically!!!

Comment: tell when you want start intent ?

Comment: To try and understand what you want to achieve are you wanting this: Activity A launches Activity B. After 2 minutes Activity B closes and returns to Activity A?

Comment: Scan Activity is created by you?

Comment: If I understand you...the intent opens the Barcode Scanner application which is installed on my phone.And I want that app to be closed automatticaly after 2 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many problems here.

cancel() does not forcibly stop a task from executing right in the middle of its execution. It prevents it from running if it hasn't already.

Even if it did, it would not do what you want. Your runnable launches an entirely different Activity and returns immediately. It does not block, or wait. It's already finished 2 minutes later.

Even if it didn't -- interrupting this call would have no effect on the other Activity. You can forcibly close another Activity (well, not without certain permission from the platform).

Your timeout is not 2 minutes, but 20 seconds.